# Can someone provide me with an example of MVC coding in Python?

Tags: python, model-view-controller, user-interface

I think I understand the basic idea behind coding in the Model/View Controller Method. It's done to segregate areas of a program, so that if someone accesses a part of a program, they don't automatically access all of the data. But can someone provide me with an example of how to make a GUI using MVC? Here's a sample GUI. How do I turn this into an MVC GUI?

```
from tkinter import *

class Application(Frame):
    """ GUI application that creates a story based on user input. """
    def __init__(self, master):
        """ Initialize Frame. """
        super(Application, self).__init__(master)  
        self.grid()
        self.create_widgets()

    def create_widgets(self):
        """ Create widgets to get story information and to display story. """
        # create instruction label
        Label(self,
              text = "Enter information for a new story"
              ).grid(row = 0, column = 0, columnspan = 2, sticky = W)

        # create a label and text entry for the name of a person
        Label(self,
              text = "Person: "
              ).grid(row = 1, column = 0, sticky = W)
        self.person_ent = Entry(self)
        self.person_ent.grid(row = 1, column = 1, sticky = W)

        # create a label and text entry for a plural noun
        Label(self,
              text = "Plural Noun:"
              ).grid(row = 2, column = 0, sticky = W)
        self.noun_ent = Entry(self)
        self.noun_ent.grid(row = 2, column = 1, sticky = W)

        # create a label and text entry for a verb
        Label(self,
              text = "Verb:"
              ).grid(row = 3, column = 0, sticky = W)
        self.verb_ent = Entry(self)
        self.verb_ent.grid(row = 3, column = 1, sticky = W)

        # create a label for adjectives check buttons
        Label(self,
              text = "Adjective(s):"
              ).grid(row = 4, column = 0, sticky = W)

        # create itchy check button
        self.is_itchy = BooleanVar()
        Checkbutton(self,
                    text = "itchy",
                    variable = self.is_itchy
                    ).grid(row = 4, column = 1, sticky = W)

        # create joyous check button
        self.is_joyous = BooleanVar()
        Checkbutton(self,
                    text = "joyous",
                    variable = self.is_joyous
                    ).grid(row = 4, column = 2, sticky = W)

        # create electric check button
        self.is_electric = BooleanVar()
        Checkbutton(self,
                    text = "electric",
                    variable = self.is_electric
                    ).grid(row = 4, column = 3, sticky = W)

        # create a label for body parts radio buttons
        Label(self,
              text = "Body Part:"
              ).grid(row = 5, column = 0, sticky = W)

        # create variable for single, body part
        self.body_part = StringVar()
        self.body_part.set(None)

        # create body part radio buttons
        body_parts = ["bellybutton", "big toe", "medulla oblongata"]
        column = 1
        for part in body_parts:
            Radiobutton(self,
                        text = part,
                        variable = self.body_part,
                        value = part
                        ).grid(row = 5, column = column, sticky = W)
            column += 1

        # create a submit button
        Button(self,
               text = "Click for story",
               command = self.tell_story
               ).grid(row = 6, column = 0, sticky = W)

        self.story_txt = Text(self, width = 75, height = 10, wrap = WORD)
        self.story_txt.grid(row = 7, column = 0, columnspan = 4)

    def tell_story(self):
        """ Fill text box with new story based on user input. """
        # get values from the GUI
        person = self.person_ent.get()
        noun = self.noun_ent.get()
        verb = self.verb_ent.get()
        adjectives = ""
        if self.is_itchy.get():
            adjectives += "itchy, "
        if self.is_joyous.get():
            adjectives += "joyous, "
        if self.is_electric.get():
            adjectives += "electric, "
        body_part = self.body_part.get()

        # create the story
        story = "The famous explorer "
        story += person
        story += " had nearly given up a life-long quest to find The Lost City of "
        story += noun.title()
        story += " when one day, the "
        story += noun
        story += " found "
        story += person + ". "
        story += "A strong, "
        story += adjectives
        story += "peculiar feeling overwhelmed the explorer. "
        story += "After all this time, the quest was finally over. A tear came to "
        story += person + "'s "
        story += body_part + ". "
        story += "And then, the "
        story += noun
        story += " promptly devoured "
        story += person + ". "
        story += "The moral of the story? Be careful what you "
        story += verb
        story += " for."

        # display the story                                
        self.story_txt.delete(0.0, END)
        self.story_txt.insert(0.0, story)

# main
def main():
    root = Tk()
    root.title("Mad Lib")
    app = Application(root)
    root.mainloop()

main()
```

Comment: Rather than for segregation, MVC is more for flexibility: if done right, you will be able to change view (roughly speaking, GUI), without touching models (data) and with very few modifications to controller logic.

Answer (score 0):

I have only used tkinter one time so this might seem rather generic.

It seems logical that your application might have a Story Model and a Story View.

All your story logic could be contained in the story model.  The story model could be responsible for drawing the story view (all the story widgets)

I think the important thing is to recognize that perhaps your `Application` class is not the appropriate place to contain your story logic.  Even though there has to be one entry point into your tkinter application the Application class might not best represent your data.

In the above suggestion the Application could still function as a controller, which could be responsable for instantiating your Story Model

There are probably multiple ways to apply MVC to your app, so please don't take my suggestion as the only one

Comment: I was hoping for something more specific, but I'll try to work something out with your suggestion.